# spring-data-elasticsearch search template

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

We have a few similar queries and I wanted to do some templating based on parameters. Recently I've found that elastic supports [search templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html) so I'm wondering whether this is supported by [spring-data-elasticearch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch).

Currently my query looks something like:

```
final Query query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().addAggregation(aggregationBuilder)
      .withPageable(EmptyPage.INSTANCE)
      .withQuery(queryBuilder)
      .build();
```

I'm wondering if I can somehow pass the template that I've stored in application and get the result from elastic. Or if I can store the template in elastic and get the result based on parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Spring Data Elasticsearch currently does not support search templates.

**Edit 16.03.2021:** search template support has been added to the `ReactiveElasticsearchClient`in Spring Data Elasticsearch by a pull request from [bilak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266254/bilak). Thanks for that.